# Nodejs: How to catch exception in net.createServer.on("data",...)?

Tags: sockets, node.js, exception

I've got a standard socket-server (NO HTTP) setup as follows (contrived):

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  c.on('data', function(data) {
    //do stuff here
    //some stuff can result in an exception that isn't caught anywhere downstream, 
    //so it bubbles up. I try to catch it here. 
    //this is the same problem as just trying to catch this: 
    throw new Error("catch me if you can");
  });
}).listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
   console.log('socket server started on port 8124,');
});
```

Now the thing is I've got some code throwing errors that aren't catched at all, crashing the server. As a last measure I'd like to catch them on this level, but anything I've tried fails.

- `server.on("error",....)`
- `c.on("error",...)`

Perhaps I need to get to the socket instead of `c` (the connection), although I'm not sure how.

I'm on Node 0.6.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
process.on('uncaughtException',function(err){
   console.log('something terrible happened..')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work to make sure the node-process doesn't get killed. However, I believe this will not keep the socket-server from halting. I'll give it a try though

Comment: Excepting as only correct answer.. although a bit unsatisfactory for my use-case.

Comment: can you provide more information where and when the error is thrown? 
do you throw the error yourself? the best thing would be not to throw at all, instead pass the error back with a callback to handle them correctly.

Comment: indeed, for most of the time I do pass the error using callbacks `callback(err,result)` etc. It's the uncaught exceptions I was worried about.. They could happen deep doen in the domain layer. All sorted now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the Exceptions yourself.  There is no event on either connection or server objects which would allow you to handle exception the way you described.  You should add exception handling logic into your event handlers to avoid server crash like this:

```
c.on('data', function(data) {
  try {
     // even handling code
  }
  catch(exception) {
    // exception handling code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not possible 9 times out of 10, since I'm doing *ASYNC*-calls to the domain layer. Having a try/catch around an async-call will not include the async-code inside the try-block, thus an error thrown by the domain is never caught. Of course, most exceptions are caught by the domain itself, however there's always the unexpected..